# How to make auto select option on current page

Tags: html, html-select

I try this code but not auto select in active select.

```
<FORM NAME="nav">
<SELECT NAME="SelectURL" onChange="document.location.href=document.nav.SelectURL.options[document.nav.SelectURL.selectedIndex].value">
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.lam-alif.com/forumdisplay.php/264?field5=Jakarta" <vb:if condition="$GLOBALS[field5] == Jakarta">SELECTED</vb:if>>Utama
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.lam-alif.com/forumdisplay.php/265?field5=Lampung" <vb:if condition="$GLOBALS[field5] == Bandung">SELECTED</vb:if>>Kedua
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/choices.html">Choices in HTML forms
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/tables.html">Tables and forms
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html">Form submission methods (GET and POST)
</SELECT>
</FORM>
```

how to make like this site www.tokobagus.com

Answer (score 0):

In document.ready u have to copy html of select element and change it to ul and change the options to li. After it use jquery scroller to scroll.